# Google App Engine java.lang.ExceptionInInitializer

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have an app engine connected android application. When I try to make a backend api call the device receives a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on my EMF file in the log cat. then when I  check the log on the app engine dashboard, I see java.lang.ExceptionInInitialzer error.

EMF.java

```
package com.theincrowd;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class EMF {
    protected static final EntityManagerFactory emfInstance = 
            Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    private EMF() {
    }

    public static EntityManagerFactory get() {
        return emfInstance;
    }
}
```

here is the log from the app engine console

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: Could not initialize class com.theincrowd.EMF
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.theincrowd.EMF
    at com.theincrowd.PromoterEndpoint.getEntityManager(PromoterEndpoint.java:171)
    at com.theincrowd.PromoterEndpoint.insertPromoter(PromoterEndpoint.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:337)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:162)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:120)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:483)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:490)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:777)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:754)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:345)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:337)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:487)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

And I read the explanation in this article http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2012/07/javalangnoclassdeffounderror-how-to.html
however, I was unable to identify the problem in the code.